# Values cannot be inserted into my database after choosing from drop down list submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to insert the values from my form after clicking an option from my drop down list. However, it keeps telling me that my **LINE 4** and **LINE 5** of my ***submit.php*** has error. I do not know what is wrong with my $_POST statement.

Please enlighten me, I am very new to PHP and HTML.

Below is my code for my drop down list.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<head>

<title> Search by Development </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content ="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>


<body>
    <form name="form1" action="submit.php" method="post">
      <label type='text'> Name:</label>
      <select name ='userID'>
          <?php 
          $conn1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','carpark_project'); 
          $result1 = $conn1->query("select userid from user");

          while($row =$result1->fetch_assoc())
          { ?>
          <option value="<? php echo $row['userid']; ?>">
              <?php echo $row['userid']; ?>
          </option>

          <?php
          } ?>

      </select>

      <br>

       <label type='text'> Development:</label>
      <select name ='Development'>
          <?php 
          $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','carpark_project'); 
          $result = $conn->query("select development from carpark");

          while($row =$result->fetch_assoc())
          { ?>
          <option value="<? php echo $row['development']; ?>">
              <?php echo $row['development']; ?>
          </option>

          <?php
          } ?>

      </select>
       <br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the action PHP file.

```
<?php
 $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','carpark_project');

$development = $_POST['Development'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$inserthistory = "Insert into history (userid, development) values ('$userid','$development')";

  $result=mysqli_query($con,$inserthistory);

  if($result)
  {
    header("refresh:5; url=history.php");
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Not Updated";
  }

?>
```

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `$userid = $_POST['userID'];`

Also use prepared statements here to prevent sql injection attacks

```
$inserthistory = "Insert into history (userid, development) values (? , ?)"; #create sql string with placeholders to prevent sql injection
$sql = $con->prepare($inserthistory); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 
$sql->bind_param('ss' , $userid, $development); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
if ($sql->execute() === true){ #execute it
#query successful 
} else {
#error
echo $con->error; 
}
```

Also just an important observation.  You should have one file containing the database connection. Currently you are creating a new database connection for every form input which is bad..  Create a file and then establish the connection there. Then all you do is include that file where you need.

Comment: Though the question should be closed as "typographical error" I'm upvoting this answer due to providing "good practice", though the questioner might not even understand the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually flagged it as a typo though. I added this answer cos OP seems like a newbie. I'll add comments

Answer (score 0):

Change `<select name ='userID'>` to `<select name ='userid'>`